# Storing big decimals in MySQL

Tags: mysql

how can I store large decimal values in MYSQL?

I have tried to use the `decimal(10,9)` but the value ends up being transformed to: `99999999.99`

Example: `2110624448.26533720`

Expected save value: `2110624448.26533720`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you want to store a value like `2110624448.26533720` which has a precision of 10 and a scale of 8

```
CREATE TABLE table (column DECIMAL(18, 8));
```

`DECIMAL(18, 8)` specifies a total of 18 digits (including both integer and decimal parts) and 8 decimal places.

If you've already created the table, use the ALTER TABLE statement to modify the column:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column DECIMAL(18, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the value `2110624448.26533720` without any loss of precision, you need to adjust the precision and scale of your `DECIMAL` column.

For example, if you want to store values with up to 8 digits to the left of the `.` and 8 digits to the right of the `.`, you can define your column as `DECIMAL(16, 8)`:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    your_decimal_column DECIMAL(16, 8)
);
```

This will allow you to store values like 2110624448.26533720 without any rounding.

Comment: Not worked as expected... the result still is: 99999999.99999999
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` CHANGE `VALUE` `VALUE` DECIMAL(16,8) NOT NULL;

Comment: It's because he said "for example, 8 digits left of the decimal and 8 digits right".  While this example doesn't match your use case, it is still technically correct, you just have to adjust to your actual precision and scale.